# Facebook App Details rejected for not appearing to integrate Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, android-facebook

I keep having my app details page rejected with this message:

> Your Android app does not appear to have Facebook Login integration. Please either implement Facebook Login or remove this integration as a listed platform in the developer app. See more details here

I do use Facebook Login in my app. Who can I contact to resolve this issue?

What really does not make sense is the free version of my app was approved, but the paid version keeps getting rejected, when they integrate Facebook Login the exact same way!

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app details page is eventually accepted after repeatedly submitting for review after each rejection, and referencing this page in my submission message.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the last version of facebook Sdk ? You have to uprade to 3.0.. 
 Go on your facebook application and check :
- Your alerts, your solution should be here
- Settings -> Android native application -> enable facebook login

Comment: I am using 3.0, and yes I have enabled facebook login in Settings, because I am actually using it. As far as I know, I have Facebook Login properly integrated with Facebook SDK 3.0. I just can't figure out why the app details page keeps getting rejected, as every time I just get a generic message, even after I describe in detail how Facebook Login is integrated into the app.